# Achieving multicolumn like this

Tags: two-column

I wan to achieve multi-column like shown below:

[image]

But the only thing I can get is:

[image]

With the code below:

```
{\LARGE Albert Einstein}\\[1cm]
Institute for Advanced Study\\   Einstein Drive\\   Princeton, N.J. \texttt{08540}
U.S.A.\\[.2cm]
Phone: \texttt{609-734-8000}\\   Fax: \texttt{609-924-8399}\\[.2cm]
email: \href{mailto:a.einstein@ias.edu}{a.einstein@ias.edu}\\   \textsc{url}: \href{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/}{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/}\\
```

What should I add to/how should I modify the code to achieve something like the first screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Hopefully, you can modify it to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{bbding}
\newcommand*\splitline[3]{%
        \hbox to.5\textwidth{#1\hfil}%
        \hbox to2em{#2\hfil}%
        \hbox{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\Huge Dario Taraborelli}\\[2\baselineskip]
\href{http://cress.soc.surrey.ac.uk/}
        {Centre for Research in Social Simulation}\\
\splitline{Department of Sociology}{\textsc{t}}{+44 (0)1483 683961}\\
\splitline{University of Surrey}{\textsc{f}}{+44 (0)1483 689551}\\
\splitline{Guldford GU\textsubscript{2} {}\textsubscript{7}XH}
        {\raisebox{-.6ex}{\Envelope}}
        {\href{mailto:d.taraborelli@surrey.ac.uk}{d.taraborelli@surrey.ac.uk}}\\
\splitline{United Kingdom}{@}{\url{http://nitens.org/taraborelli}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But when how do I a space between T and Mail - the vertical space as in the above. Anyway this is nice.

Comment: @Ujjwol: I don't know what space you mean?

Comment: I am talking about the space between "+44 (0)1483 689551" and "✉ d.taraborelli@surrey.ac.uk".

Comment: @Ujjwol: I see. That takes a little more work. Jan Hlavacek's answer looks like it adds some space. I actually think the space looks bad since the text is no longer aligned.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. As I had shorter text it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you can achieve something like this.  First, you can use the `multicol` package, and do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}
\noindent{\LARGE Albert Einstein}\\[1cm]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Institute for Advanced Study
\vfill

Einstein Drive\\
Princeton, N.J. \texttt{08540}
U.S.A.
\columnbreak

\noindent Phone: \texttt{609-734-8000}\\
Fax: \texttt{609-924-8399}\\[.2cm]
email: \href{mailto:a.einstein@ias.edu}{a.einstein@ias.edu}\\
\textsc{url}: \href{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/}{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Another way would be using two parboxes or minipages whose width is exactly of
the width of the text. In this case you do not need any additional packages.

```
\vspace{1in}

\noindent{\LARGE Albert Einstein}\\[1cm]
\parbox[b]{.5\hsize}{
\noindent Institute for Advanced Study\\
Einstein Drive\\
Princeton, N.J. \texttt{08540}
U.S.A.}%
\parbox[b]{.5\hsize}{
Phone: \texttt{609-734-8000}\\
Fax: \texttt{609-924-8399}\\[.2cm]
email: \href{mailto:a.einstein@ias.edu}{a.einstein@ias.edu}\\
\textsc{url}: \href{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/}{http://www.ias.edu/spfeatures/einstein/} 
}
```

Notice that in both cases, the vertical spacing between lines is an issue, you
have to manually tune the spacing so that the lines will come up "alligned".

I don't know if there is any way LaTeX can do this automatically for you, but
it can be done with ConTeXt, which supports [typesetting on a grid](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf).

Comment: I edited the answer a bit, so some of the vertical space problems disappear, but it is still not ideal.  One possible way, when using the `multicol` package,  is to typeset each line as a separate paragraph, with `\vfill` between them.  Then the lines in the shorter column will be equally spaced and spread so that they will span the height of the longer column. I tried to do `\\[1\fill]` between lines, but that does not seem to work.