# How to format code snippets with a custom environment or command?

Tags: macros, two-column, verbatim

I'd like to make an environment or command to wrap the this [2-column REPL formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403815/how-to-achieve-this-two-column-style/403826?noredirect=1#comment1006120_403826). For example, as a command (`\format{TEXT}{CODE}`) it would look like this:

```
\format2cols{
Description of the code
}{
The actual code
}
```

*Having a shortcut like this would clean up my document exponentially!*

Here's what it looks like, with the TEXT is on the left and the CODE on the right:

[image]
The difficulty here is that LaTex **doesn't allow for passing verbatim arguments**.  So I'm at an impasse.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlength\textlen
\newlength\codelen
\newlength\halflen
\setlength\halflen{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\textlen{.95\halflen}
\setlength\codelen{1.05\halflen}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\usepackage{minted}    
\setminted{
    baselinestretch=1,
    tabsize=4,
    fontsize=\fontsize{8}{11}
}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont

\justify
We restrict our sorting functions to permutations of the numbers $1\cdots n$. A simple way to visualize the amount of ``sortedness'' in such a list of numbers is a picture obtained with {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\texttt{ListPlot}}.
\vspace{1.5mm}

{
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\def\arraystretch{2}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textlen}p{\codelen}@{}}
This definition is used to plot permutations of the numbers $1\cdots n$ with suitable settings of graphics options. &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{Mathematica}
In[1]:= PermutationPlot[l_List, opts___] := 
            ListPlot[ l, 
                PlotRange -> { {0.5, Length[l]+0.5},
                               {0.5, Length[l]+0.5} },
                PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.75/Length[l]],
                opts, Axes->None, FrameTicks->None,
                Frame->True, AspectRatio->1 ]
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
}
\vspace{1.5mm}

\justify
Sed efficitur diam eget ante elementum pharetra. Nullam dignissim pulvinar molestie. Sed dapibus tristique feugiat.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a complete MWE?

Comment: @marmot it's in the link, but I'll paste it in

Comment: Verbatim is alway tricky. I would recommend an environment instead of a macro.

Comment: On another note: using `\fontsize` and similar macros is not recommended. If you want 12pt as default font size use it as a class option (`[12pt]{book}`) and then use macros like `\small` etc.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks I've updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use `tcolorbox` instead?

You could create your own `tcolorbox` (`mycodebox`, in my MWE) and use it as any other environment, changing only the comment and the code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlength\textlen
\newlength\codelen
\newlength\halflen
\setlength\halflen{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\setlength\textlen{.95\halflen}
\setlength\codelen{1.05\halflen}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\setminted{
    baselinestretch=1,
    tabsize=4,
    fontsize=\fontsize{8}{11}
}
\newtcblisting{mycodebox}[2][]{%
    comment side listing,
    sidebyside align=top,   
    halign=justify,
    colframe=white, 
    colback=white,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt, 
    boxsep=0pt,
    after=\vspace{-16pt},
    lefthand width=.4\textwidth,
    fontupper=\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont,
    minted language=Mathematica,
    minted options={baselinestretch=1,
        tabsize=4,
        fontsize=\fontsize{8}{11}},
    comment={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

    \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont

    \justify
    We restrict our sorting functions to permutations of the numbers $1\cdots n$. A simple way to visualize the amount of ``sortedness'' in such a list of numbers is a picture obtained with {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\texttt{ListPlot}}.  
    \vspace{1.5mm}

    \begin{mycodebox}{This definition is used to plot permutations of the numbers $1\cdots n$ with suitable settings of graphics options.}
In[1]:= PermutationPlot[l_List, opts___] := 
ListPlot[ l, 
PlotRange -> { {0.5, Length[l]+0.5},
    {0.5, Length[l]+0.5} },
PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.75/Length[l]],
opts, Axes->None, FrameTicks->None,
Frame->True, AspectRatio->1 ]
    \end{mycodebox}
    \begin{mycodebox}{Here is a random permutation.}
In[2]:= p1 = PermutationPlot[
{9,10,6,8,2,4,12,1,7,5,3,11},
DisplayFunction->Identity ];
    \end{mycodebox}
    \justify
    Sed efficitur diam eget ante elementum pharetra. Nullam dignissim pulvinar molestie. Sed dapibus tristique feugiat.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using Texpad on OSX, and it's giving me some errors regarding pigments, I have pygmentize on my path, is there something else I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Weird! Your solution works in Latexian, but not texpad.

Comment: @M.R. You have to run pdflatex with -shell-escape

Comment: Thanks for the links, it seems that `\usepackage[outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}` would work, but your code does a `\tcbuselibrary` instead?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add the line `\write18{}` to the source file. Bizarre fix, but now it works! Thanks!

Comment: One final question, is there a way to decrease the space between the two columns by X (and increase the code's width by X)? @CarLaTeX

Comment: @M.R. With `lefthand width=...` you can set the width of the first width (and, in consequence, also of the second). I set it to `.4\textwidth`, if you want the text part less wide and the code part wider, set it to `.3\textwidth`, for example. `sidebyside gap=<lenght>` sets the horizontal distance between the left-handed and right-handed part to <lenght>. See p. 119 of the [`tcolorbox` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).